# Magento REST API - Dont send email when order fails

Tags: php, magento, rest

So i'm sending an Order object (serialized as a JSON obj) to magento using the REST API. The Documentation in Magento doesn't provide enough details on what different attributes can i use in that object.

I'd like to know if I could set a flag in my Order object to tell magento not to send an email to the user when the order fails.

Example:
Order {
   customer_id: 1,
   store_id: 1,
   send_failure_emails: 0,
   order_lines: {
        ...
        ...
   }
}

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to look at the

**Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template::sendTransactional method.**

You can overload this class and add check against order success or fail with your flag type and send email notifications (based on template name).

Comment: It's actually magento that handles the email sending part. I just want to know what the correct name of the variable for telling Magento not to send email if the order fails. Right now i currently use "send_failure_emails", but Magento doesn't seem to recognize that.

Comment: try with `is_customer_notified` as Boolean value,may be it will work for you